# Borel Sigma Algebra Of One Point Compactification

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $X$ is a noncompact locally compact hausdorff space, so that it has a one point compactification. Let $X^{\ast}$ denote the alexandroff extension with the usual topology, i.e. $\tau_{X^{\ast}} = \tau_{X} \cup \{\{\infty\} \cup V : X \setminus V \subset X$ compact $ \}$, and the compactification the inclusion map. My textbook states that $$\sigma(\tau_{X^{\ast}}) = \sigma(\tau_{X} \cup \{\infty\})$$, which as far as I can tell is true (by checking each class generating each sigma algebra is contained in the other sigma algebra). What I also believe to be true, but I have yet to confirm via literature, is that if $A \subset X^{\ast}$ is borel, then either $A$ does not contain the additional point, and is thus borel in $X$, or $A$ contains the additional point, and is of the form $\{\infty\} \cup A'$ where $A' = A \setminus \{\infty\}$ is borel in $X$. This seems true to me as the inclusion map is necessarily measurable, but it was not explicitly stated in the text I'm using (Kallenberg - Foundations of Modern Probability), perhaps because it is intended to be noted as an immediate corollary.

I would be grateful if anyone can verify the legitimacy of this second claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show that

$$\sigma(\tau_{X^*})=\sigma(\tau_X\cup\{\infty\})=:\mathscr{F}$$

as you claimed.  Let $U\in \tau_{X^*}$ so that $U\in \tau_X$ or $U=\{\infty\}\cup V$ where $V$ is the complement of a compact set in the space $(X,\tau_X)$.  In the former case, we immediately have $U\in\mathscr{F}$.  In the latter, we note that every compact set in $(X,\tau_X)$ is closed (by the Hausdorff property), so $V,V\cup\{\infty\}\in\mathscr{F}$.  This proves $\sigma(\tau_{X^*})\subseteq \mathscr{F}$.  Conversely, note that $\tau_X\subseteq\tau_{X^*}$ and in particular $X\in\tau_{X^*}$ so that $\{\infty\}=X^*\setminus X\in\sigma(\tau_{X^*})$.  This completes the proof of the claim.

Note that the collection
$$\mathscr{G}:= \sigma(\tau_X) \cup \{U\cup\{\infty\} : U\in\sigma(\tau_X)\}$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Since $\mathscr{G}$ contains every set in $\tau_X\cup\{\infty\}$, it contains $\mathscr{F}$.  Conversely, $\mathscr{F}$ contains $\sigma(\tau_X)$ along with all sets of the form $U\cup\{\infty\}$ for $U\in\sigma(\tau_X)$.  Thus $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{F}$ as required.

Comment: Didn't you even show that $\tau_{X^\ast}=\tau_X\cup\{\infty\}$ in the first part of your answer?

Comment: @0xbadf00d $\tau_X\cup\{\infty\}$ in general isn't a topology so it cannot equal $\tau_{X^*}$.